# zsh: command not found: flask after trying to execute "flask" command || python -m flask run also gives the same error

Tags: python, flask, pip

I installed flask using pip3. but when I type and enter `flask` I get this error:

```
zsh: command not found: flask
```

I looked up over stackoverflow and found to use `python -m flask run` but this also gives the same error `zsh: command not found: flask`

When I again execute `pip3 install flask` so I get prompts that flask is already installed.

Can anyone help what shall I do ?

Inside a virtual environment I am able to install flask easily. How is it possible I can install inside virtual env ?

Comment: The flask package does not include an executable called *flask*. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: just typing out flask in terminal to see if it was installed. like we type python and see information being printed out

Comment: You can't do that with Python packages. If you need to check then use the following commands: `pip list` - list all installed packages. `pip show flask` - display details about a single package.

Comment: Following the comment by @Jean-BaptisteQuenot it appears there is actually a flask executable. This should be in the same location as the python and pip application, so it should be callable in your shell. So you need to inspect the contents of your python installation tree to check whwere it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell because you don't mention your operating system, but you should try to use `python3` instead of `python`.

Your shell will look for `PATH` to find binaries. Also setting the `PATH` environment variable will help to locate where the `flask` executable has been installed.

Comment: thanks. how can i set the PATH?

Comment: The issue is that the questioner is typing `flask` at the command prompt, thinking that it is a simple executable. But *Flask* is a Python package and cannot be instantiated in that way. And changing the `PATH` variable will have no effect.

Comment: Mr OldBoy I read the documentation prior to replying: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/

It says: To run the application, use the `flask` command or `python -m flask`

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteQuenot My apologies, I have just checked again, and there is indeed a flask executable. If you edit your response I can upvote it for you.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Quenot my OS is sonoma 14.3.1. 
Also i am using python3 only. i am not able to find resources of how to set PATH env variable